# Applying for loops on dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am applying for loop to a column in python. But I am not able to execute it. It is producing error. I want square of a column. Please see where I am committing mistake. I know i can do this with `lambda`. But I want to perform it in traditional way.

```
import pandas as pd

output=[]
for i in pd.read_csv("infy.csv"):
    output.append(i['Close']**2)
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the whole point of pandas is not to loop

```
output = pd.read_csv("infy.csv")['Close']**2
```